# failed to deploy a contract to the local blockchain of Ganache using Ethers

Tags: solidity, ganache

I wrote a contract demo using vscode on Windows 10, mainly deploying a contract to the local blockchain of Ganache using Ethers. However, when I executed node test.js, it reported an error as follows:
Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "**Binary string of contract**", "from": "0x58b5b7c1674f7174082BE1912869f64630F4145f", "to": null }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.11.1),how should I fix it?

By the way,My contract code is as follows：

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    // uint256[] public anArray;
    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

---

my js code is as follows：

```
const ethers = require("ethers")
const fs = require("fs-extra")

async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://rpc.sepolia.dev")
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet("f2a0b5a745aa68a7c2343314f0376152329175ec2382fcbc32dc0fb87e6738e7", provider);
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi","utf8")
  const bin = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin","utf8")
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bin, wallet)
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy()
  console.log(contract)
}

main()
.then(()=>process.exit(0))
.catch((error)=>{
    console.log("----:"+error)
    process.exit(1)
})
```

---

my nodejs version is v20.11.1
my ethers version is ^6.11.1

Compile and execute code commands：
yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o . SimpleStorage.sol
node test.js

I hope everyone can help me identify the possible causes of code errors and successfully execute the release contract code

Answer (score 0):

*The code snippet in your question contains a private key. Never share your private key on the internet. You should consider this key compromised - anyone can steal any funds on any network from the address derived from this key - so you might want to use a different key from now on.*

---

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://rpc.sepolia.dev")
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet("<privatekey>", provider);
// ...
const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bin, wallet)
const contract = await contractFactory.deploy()
```

This snippet tries to deploy the contract to the Sepolia testnet - not to your local emulator.

The [deployer address](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x58b5b7c1674f7174082BE1912869f64630F4145f) doesn't have any Sepolia ETH to pay for the deployment transaction.

Instead of the `rpc.sepolia.dev` RPC URL, use your local emulator's URL. I believe Ganache uses `http://127.0.0.1:7545` (UI) or `http://127.0.0.1:8545` (CLI) by default. If you want, you can override the default URL in settings (Ganache UI) or with the `--server.host` and `--server.port` options (Ganache CLI, see the [docs](https://archive.trufflesuite.com/docs/ganache/reference/cli-options/)).

Example fix:

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The private key you mentioned was only generated on the testing network, and I will also pay attention to your suggestions in future development. Thank you. Also, my code may have caused you to misunderstand. I have no problem using ganache locally, and this error should not be a problem with connecting to ganache or the sepolia network. Therefore, I am wondering if it may be a Solidity version or other issue